# Decode a nested array with circe-optics

Tags: scala, circe, circe-optics

I have JSON like this:

```
  "data": {
    "project": {
      "activityChildren": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "parents": [
            {
              "id": 1
            }
          ]
        },

      ]
    }
  }
```

I'd like to decode this to `List[(Long, List[Long])]` with circe-optics.  I got as far as:

```
  val activityParents: Map[Long, List[Long]] = root.data.activityChildren.each.json
      .getAll(json)
      .flatMap { activity =>
        root.id.long.getOption(activity).map(_ -> root.parents.each.long.getAll(activity))
      }
      .toMap
```

I wonder whether it's possible to define a single lens for this that just turns the JSON into the desired map without explicitly mapping over the intermediate array.  If so, how?